# WebSocket (html/ visual studio)

Tags: html, visual-studio, websocket

Возникли проблемы с реализацией через visual studio.
В html(в браузере) данные через сокет отправляются и я получаю ответ с данными.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>        
    <script language="javascript">     
CAPIWS = (typeof EIMZOEXT !== 'undefined') ? EIMZOEXT : { 
    callFunction: function(funcDef, callback, error)
    { 
        var socket;
        try{            socket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:64443/service/cryptapi");        } 
        catch (e){             error(e);         }
        //Ответ сокета
        console.log(socket);
        socket.onmessage = function(event){
        console.log(event.data);
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        //  console.log(data);
            socket.close();
            callback(event,data);
        };      
        //запрос сокета
        socket.onopen = function(){   
        console.log(funcDef);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(funcDef));
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(funcDef));   
        };      
    },      
};  

getallkeys();

function getallkeys(){
//запрос всех сертификатов
CAPIWS.callFunction({
    plugin    :"pfx",
    name      :"list_all_certificates"
  },
  function(event, data){  
    for (var key in data.certificates) {
    var element = data.certificates[key];
    }   
  },
  function(error){
    window.alert(error);
  }
);
};

    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Делаю ту же операцию, как мне кажется, в visual studio
с сокетом соединение происходит, но при отправке данных получаю ответ (ошибку)
**"reason": "Не удалось идентифицировать домен.", "success": false**

```
  private async Task send02()
        {
            using (ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                Uri serviceuri = new Uri("wss://127.0.0.1:64443/service/cryptapi");
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
                try
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync(serviceuri, cts.Token);
                    var n = 0;
                    while (client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        string message = "{\"plugin\": \"pfx\", \"name\": \"list_all_certificates\"}";
                        ArraySegment<byte> bytetosend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                        await client.SendAsync(bytetosend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cts.Token);
                        var responsbuffer = new byte[1024];
                        var offset = 0;
                        var paket = 1024;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            ArraySegment<byte> bytetorecive = new ArraySegment<byte>(responsbuffer, offset, paket);
                            WebSocketReceiveResult responce = await client.ReceiveAsync(bytetorecive, cts.Token);
                            var responsemessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsbuffer, offset, responce.Count);
                            Console.WriteLine(responsemessage);
                            if (responce.EndOfMessage)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebSocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            };

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

спасибо Azamat M, подсказал что сделать. client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Origin", "127.0.0.1");